# how to change the control position of the drawing manager with the @react-google-maps/api

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, react-google-maps

I'm trying to change the position of the drawing manager control panel (the one that lets the user select what shape to draw).

However, I'm having difficulties doing so.

I figured that the position values `google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER` are just numbers. So according to the [docs](https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.app/#drawingmanager) I'm trying to pass in the position object similar to the example [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawinglayer)

```
<DrawingManager
       onLoad={this.handleLoadDrawing}
       drawingMode="rectangle"
       onOverlayComplete={(e)=>console.log(e.overlay.bounds)}
       options={
          {
               position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER
          }
       }    
/>
```

I also tried `drawingControlOptions` instead of `options` but no difference. What am I doing wrong? I created a codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-mountain-ihr9h?file=/src/Map.js).

Comment: `position: 2`? Where does that come from? Anyway if you need help with this, you should provide a [mcve]. And use options and properties according to the docs.

Comment: right, sorry, I updated it with a codesandbox, `position: 2` is supposed to be `position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER` those constants are just numbers. I got rid off them cause I wanted to prevent google not being loaded errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am really no React expert and as it seems they can't provide one working example in the official docs, I am not too sure how it *should* be done.

The official solution I believe is here: https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.app/#usejsapiloader but I could not get this to work.

So far, the only way I was able to get your above code working was by doing 2 things: 1) move the drawing manager to a separate component, and 2) use `/* global google */` in the component.

```
/* global google */
import React from "react";
import { DrawingManager } from "@react-google-maps/api";

const DrawingComponent = () => {
  const onLoad = (drawingManager) => {
    console.log("drawingManager", drawingManager);
  };

  const onPolygonComplete = (polygon) => {
    console.log("polygoncomplete", polygon);
  };

  return (
    <DrawingManager
      onLoad={onLoad}
      onPolygonComplete={onPolygonComplete}
      options={{
        drawingControl: true,
        drawingControlOptions: {
          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT,
          drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON]
        },
        polygonOptions: { editable: true }
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default DrawingComponent;
```

Working code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-poitras-i9rg3?file=/src/DrawingCmp.js

Comment: woahhhh, thank you so much! I should have seen that the options should have looked like this: `{options: {drawingControlOptions: ... }}` but I was wondering how did you figure out that use `apiloader` did the trick? Based on the documentation it says you need to use this to avoid google not found error, but i don't recall running into this issue. I'm trying to retrace your steps so that I can learn from it for my next issue lol. THANK YOU!

Comment: Let's make it clear: yes, the format for the options is confirmed and works as in the code I posted. Regarding `useJsApiLoader`, I found about it by reading the docs, but I have **not** implemented it in the sandbox I posted. I tried their example and couldn't get it to work. By reading the docs, it seems though that it's the preferred way as it says it is *the alternative variant of LoadScript and useLoadScript hook that tries to solve the problem of "google is not defined" error*. The sandbox code uses `LoadScript`. It works, but you might want to try with `useJsApiLoader` too.